# Azure devops build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I have created a sample Website project with a single page having HellowWord.aspx and HellowWord.aspx.cs. I am trying to create an Azure DevOps build pipeline for this project. The following are the tasks I have added to my build package.

[image: Task List]

But the publish artifacts always contains the aspx and aspx.cs file. Not sure which tasks I am supposed to add to make the proper publish package. Which will create proper dlls for .aspx file instead of aspx.cs.

[image: Artifacts files]

Comment: You need to copy correct files to StagingDirectory. Please check your definition of copy files? Also, whay do you publish symbols, do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

`Publish build artifacts` task has an argument `Path to publish`, which defines the folder or file path to publish. This can be a fully-qualified path or a path relative to the root of the repository. Wildcards are not supported. Variables are supported. Example: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. By default, this argument uses variable `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

So you need to check your `Copy files` task, to see what you have copied to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, and copy the correct files in this task.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Hi, @CeceDong I have set the correct copy files path from the root directory. [Which is HelloWorld folder in the solution.]

Comment: You could use Exclude patterns by leading `!` changes the meaning of an include pattern to exclude: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops.

Comment: Hi, @CeceDong, '!' will exclude the files. If I exclude the files then where I am going to get the publish package files like dlls files?

Comment: You need to specify the correct content path in `Copy files` task. For example, if your want to publish dll files in `Bin` folder in the root directory, you can specify `**\bin\*.dll` in `Contents` field.

Comment: How's your issue going?